# References and speed

Tags: clojure, datomic

Are references bi-directional, in the sense that given `?cat`, datomic does no searching to find the related entity, `?person`, in a `[?person :pet ?cat]` restriction?

Or should I manually build a reference in the other side (e.g. setting an `:owner` attribute for pets) to prevent a linear search in all the `?person`s that have `:pet`s?

Comment: What do you mean by "no time" and "manually build the references"?

Comment: Hi, lgrapenthin, I've updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no speed advantage to storing both sides of a relation explicitly, [all relations are bi-directional](http://docs.datomic.com/tutorial.html) in datomic.